# Alternative layout for single article menu item possible?

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, template-override, layout

I created an alternative layout for an article (in **templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/newlayout.php**). I can see it in the Layout option of the Article => OK

Actually, I would prefer to set this layout from a menu item. I created a menu item as '**Single Article**' Menu Item Type but I can't see it in the Template Style option. I added a newlayout.xml (based on default.xml) in **templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/article/** but it does not change anything.

Is it possible to set an article layout directly from a menu item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, It is available as a Menu Item Type so it's OK.